# Why does my python:3.8-alpine based application crash on a syntax error inside importlib_metadata

Tags: python, python-3.x, dockerfile, alpine-linux, python-importlib

I am facing a problem launching my containerized server which worked fine natively, the problem is that it crashes on runtime. Here is the output for the **docker-compose** command:

```
zos_context    |   File "/code/redis_client.py", line 4, in <module>
zos_context    |     import redis
zos_context    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
zos_context    |     import importlib_metadata as metadata
zos_context    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 55
zos_context    |     return f"No package metadata was found for {self.name}"
zos_context    |                                                           ^
zos_context    | SyntaxError: invalid syntax
zos_context exited with code 1
```

The image that I'm using is **python:3.8-alpine**. I have also tried **python:3.7-alpine** and even **python:3.5-alpine** but the same error always occur.

Here is a part of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /code

RUN pip3 install redis
RUN pip3 install redis pika

CMD ["python3", "/code/server.py"]`
```

Comment: Because your base image is actually Python 3.5 which does not support f-strings.

Comment: Looking at the source of the image at https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/b1791249f1a5f6e4a02bde16cca7fe75e56df76e/3.8/alpine3.15/Dockerfile it installs python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using docker-compose that just launches the container using an obsolete image, the solution is to mount the working directory from the local machine on the container to keep up with the updates.
Another solution is to use add the argument `--build` when launching using docker-compose:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```